# Disprove for all integers $a$ and $b$ there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $a = m + n$ and $b = m − n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

> Use Method of Contradiction to Disprove for all integers $a$ and $b$ there exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $a = m + n$ and $b = m − n$

I get $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{Z},\exists a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a\neq m+n$ and $b\neq m-n$
But  I don't see any information to keep going to do the question, can anyone give me a hit or suggestion ?

Thanks

Comment: Let $a=1$ and $b=0$. You will find that $m$ must be $1/2$, not an integer. So for this choice of $a$ and $b$, there do not exist integers $m$ and $n$ such that $\dots$.

Comment: For disproving any statement you only need a counterexample.

Comment: @ Ritu I forget this question ask to use contradiction. See edit

Answer (score 1):

If $a = m+n$ and $b = m-n$, then $a+b = 2m$.

Thus, a natural counter example would be any integers $a, b$ whose sum is not even (e.g. $a=0, b=1$).

As we are disproving a statement, all we need to do is show one counter example.

---

The problem with your solution is that your negation is incorrect.

The negation of

$\forall a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \exists m, n \in \mathbb{Z} a = m+n \wedge b = m-n$

is

$\exists a, b \in \mathbb{Z} \forall m, n \in \mathbb{Z} a \neq m+n \vee b \neq m-n$